# How we can have custom error message in lightning-input-address

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

How we Can have custom error Message in lightning-input-address Instead of `Complete this field.`

Expecting the error message like `Street is missing`, `City is missing`.

I checked the Document it mentioned to use `setCustomValidityForField`, I'm not sure how to handle,  Can anyone please help me on this. Thanks in Advance.

[image]

```
<template>
    <lightning-input-address
        address-label="Address"
        street-label="Street"
        city-label="City"
        country-label="Country"
        province-label="Province"
        postal-code-label="PostalCode"
        street=""
        city=""
        country=""
        province=""
        postal-code=""
        required
        field-level-help="Help Text for inputAddress field" ></lightning-input-address>


    <lightning-button label="Register"
                      onclick={register}>
    </lightning-button>
 </template>


 register(event) {
          console.log('in');
          const address = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input-address');
          console.log('address' + address);
          var value = address.value;
          console.log('value' + value);         
          address.setCustomValidityForField("Field is Required!");

          /* const address = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input-address');
           const isValid = address.checkValidity();
           if (isValid) {

           } else {
                address.reportValidity();
           }*/
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

`setCustomValidityForField` accepts validity message and field name. You then have to call report validity to show your custom field-specific message.

Sample code to explain how to use `setCustomValidityForField`

```
checkProvince(){
        var address = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input-address');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(address));
        if(address.province==='CA'){         
            address.setCustomValidityForField('Province cant be CA','province');
            address.reportValidity();
        }
    }
```

[Playground link:](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/f8e67431d8f2639e8b7649df8a11001a3f15d8f7/edit)